# Spacemacs keybindings not registering

Tags: emacs, editor, key-bindings, spacemacs

My .spacemacs file includes a section that looks like this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."

;; Keybindings
(global-unset-key [(control z)]) ;; unbind sleep button
(global-unset-key [(control x)(control z)]) ;; unbind sleep button
(global-unset-key [(control e)])
(global-unset-key [(control k)]) ;; unbind kill line
(global-set-key [(control z)] 'undo) ;; set Windows-style undo
(global-set-key [(control e)] 'View-scroll-half-page-backward) ;; remap page up

;; Setting and showing the 80-character column width
(set-fill-column 80)
(auto-fill-mode t)
(toggle-fill-column-indicator)

(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(paradox-github-token t))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  )

  )
```

I followed the syntax from this article: https://github.com/andrewfwang/dotfiles/blob/ee84ddd304d1dad7ece206062debd3e3c86e927f/.emacs.d/init.el

However, everytime I restart spacemacs, none of my changes have registered. However, if I enable or disable packages in this same file, those changes register. Should these keybinding adjustments not be under `user-config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> is slightly tricky as the spacemacs code contains a function to rebind it as one switches to emacs mode and back again. It does this through a reference to evil-toggle-key which is <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> by default. If you change evil-toggle-key to something else then you can use <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> for undo.

Suggestion: in the .spacemacs file

Add this line in the custom-set-variables section

```
'( evil-toggle-key "C-`")
```

and this line in the dotspacemacs/user-config section

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
```

The above config I have working on spacemacs version 0.200.7, emacs version 25.1.1 under both Windows and Linux

Comment: It seems that putting `'( evil-toggle-key "C-`")` in `dotspacemacs/user-config` in `custom-set-variables` is too late, since evil has already loaded by that time. However, putting `(setq evil-toggle-key "C-\`")` in the `dotspacemacs/user-init ()` section of .spacemacs seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience moose1089's answer is most of the way there, but the evil config needs to be loaded earlier than the `dotspacemacs/user-config` secion in `.spacemacs`. I found that adding `(setq evil-toggle-key "C-`")`in the`dotspacemacs/user-init ()`section of`.spacemacs` works a charm.